# How do I calculate the distance between two points?

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I have a calculate function and the latlng values but how do I calculate the distance between the first and the last?

```
 function calculate() {
         //poo abbreviation for point of origin not poo=shit
         var poolat = locations[0].lat;
         var poolng = locations[0].lng;
         var destlat = locations[locations.length - 1].lat;
         var destlng = locations[locations.length - 1].lng;
```

Comment: Your post needs a bit more info to be answered. Are you looking for the straight line distance between two points (as the crow flies)?

Comment: Yes, aerial distance, nevermind I got it working, thank you anyway sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways, you can use the Haversine formula which requires a little more typing or you can use the API.

**Try the following in your calculate function**

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
    new google.maps.LatLng(poolat, poolng), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(destlat, destlng)
);
```

console.log(distance);

**Note:**

The default value of the distance is in metres.

Answer (score 3):

This question has already been answered here: [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Note that the Haversine formula assumes a perfect sphere, not a spheroid which is what the earth is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The built in Math functions make it much easier

```
function calculate() {
     //poo abbreviation for shit
     var poolat = locations[0].lat;
     var poolng = locations[0].lng;
     var destlat = locations[locations.length - 1].lat;
     var destlng = locations[locations.length - 1].lng;

     return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((destlat - poolat),2) + Math.pow((destlng - poolng),2))
}
```